# Lightswitch Forms Authentication logout button on multiple pages?

Tags: visual-studio, forms-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

Lightswitch provides a Logout button on the Home page by default, but I'd like to have the option to log out on other pages as well. Is it possible to place the logout button on multiple pages?

Comment: Did my proposed answer help to provide a solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with the HTML client, this can easily be achieved by replacing the following line of code in the LightSwitch library's _determineButtons function: -

```js
result.showLogOut = msls_shell.getHomeScreen() === navigationUnit.screen.details.getModel();
```

With the following line of code: -

```js
result.showLogOut = true;
```

This function is located in Scripts\msls-?.?.?.js file and, in order for this type of library file change to be applied, you'll need to reference the un-minified version of the LightSwitch library by making the following change in your HTML client's default.htm file: -

```js
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/msls-?.?.?.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/msls-?.?.?.js"></script>
```

The question marks in the msls reference will need to mirror the version you're using e.g. msls-2.5.2.js (for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4).

The above approach will force the LogOut button to appear on every page.  However, if you need more control over when the LogOut button appears, you could use the following alternative change in the _determineButtons function: -

```js
result.showLogOut = window.msls.showLogOut;
```

Then, in the created method of each screen, set the msls.showLogOut property to true when you wish the button to appear and to false when you don't e.g.: -

```js
myapp.BrowseContacts.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    msls.showLogOut = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version or language. This is VB for VS2012, Lightswitch web application.

Add a button to the Screen Command Bar, call it Logout (you can choose an image for it in the Properties panel later if you want). Right click the button and select Edit Execute Code. Use the following:

```
    Private Sub Logout_Execute()
        Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(
            Sub()
                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri("../LogOut.aspx", UriKind.Relative))
            End Sub)
    End Sub
```

Works for me.

Phil